# How do I spell check directly from the magit-status buffer

Tags: magit, ispell, spell-checking, diff

Question:

Is it possible to run ispell on a region (or the whole diff and nothing else) directly from the `magit-status` buffer?

Motivation:

I am writing varying amounts of text and often keep it under version control.
I also use magit as a front-end for git.
After adding chunks of text here and there and then checking the `magit-status` I catch myself wanting to spell check newly edited regions without the hassle of diving in to the text and find it or spell-check the whole document.

Comment: Well, you can check, but you cannot fix (as the text won't be editable there). You probably know that already: `M-$` is to spellcheck a word and `M-x ispell-region` to spellcheck a region.

Comment: "the hassle of diving in to the text" - Pressing `RET` on the text in the diff will jump to the corresponding location in the file.

Comment: ispell would be harder because it is interactive, but I have implemented tooling myself to be able to perform actions on specify unstaged hunks from the status buffer. You can see this here in my config: https://github.com/jordonbiondo/.emacs.d/blob/master/jordon/jordon-magit.el . my specific use case is to run `delete-trailing-whitespace` on an unstaged hunk and save the changes from the status buffer. You may be able to use this tooling to implement what you want. See the docs for `define-magit-unstaged-hunk-action` for information on how it works.

Comment: Thanks! I will look in to your function. I have a similar one myself for just the same reason. But I don't know enough to adapt it. But I will give yours a check and see if it might be better suited for the purpose.

Comment: @npostavs Well, if you have 10 or 20 such small chunks it might be a bit tedious to dive in to each one. If you are collaborating with someone you might not want to spell check the whole document as someone else might be editing other sections and that might introduce unnecessary conflicts, and finally, if the file is a folded org file, at least for me, the subsection with the chunk is not expanded when I jump in to the file meaning I have to mess around with expanding sections where a simple mistype would jump me from the desired location. These are my main thoughts on the hassle.

Comment: I just updated the file I linked to in my config implementing the ability to ispell a unstaged magit hunk. when you run the function from a magit status buffer it will actually switch to the buffer for the hunk and ispell the hunk's region, but when ispell finishes it switches back to the refreshed magit status buffer. It may be of use to you.

Comment: @JordonBiondo Interesting! I am trying it out now, however I don't get any spell options, the messages I get are the following
Spell-checking region using aspell with english dictionary...done
save-excursion: move-to-window-line called from unrelated buffer
I have some clear spell error in the unstaged hunk. Any idea what might be the error? Basically I copied the content of your file and just ran it.

Comment: what's your magit-version?

Comment: I'm using 2.1.0 of magit

Comment: @JordonBiondo you should probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Magit does not support this and I am not aware of any third-party support. Edit: in the comments on the question there is some talk about third-party support.